# Map remote website to public folder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, cross-domain

I'm wondering if the following is possible. Let's say we have two websites http://website1.com and http://website2.com running on different servers. Is it possible to mount somehow website2 so it would be accessible via http://website1.com/folder?
the idea is to keep website1 protected since website2 is going to work on public engine, e.g. Wordpress.

Comment: Technically, by proxying the requests to the other server, but it'll usually add a decent amount of latency. I'm not sure what you think this will protect you from, though.

Comment: yeah, you're right, this solution (proxying) will not provide a better protection, plus overhead network traffic... I just wanted to ask, is it normal practice at all? does anybody do this way?